# Question about hardware

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've got a question about locks (not door locks, but like gate locks and stuff).

It's for a woodworking project (more of a carpentry project) but it's not about the wood itself, it's about lock selection.

Should I ask it here, or on DIY?

Comment: Putting a fence around your planters? :)

Comment: @Ast http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100631/lock-type-for-a-door-on-a-large-box. I've since gone for a straight hasp, learned how to weld, and welded some steel flat corner braces to keep the sides stable. Box in question is for trash cans. I never actually finished those planters, lol. Some day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is about hardware selection for a box or piece of furniture as part of a fine woodworking project, it may be on-topic here.

However, if it is more along the lines of a home improvement project, you may receive better answers on DIY.SE.